# Open HTML attachments externally in Mutt

Tags: mutt, browser, html, lynx

I recently managed to set up my mailcap so that [Mutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_(email_client)) can show HTML e-mails in the message window:

```
# ~/.mailcap
text/html; lynx -dump '%s' | more; nametemplate=%s.html; copiousoutput;
```

which is automated by:

```
# ~/.muttrc
auto_view text/html
```

Although I think [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) does a decent job on converting the HTML to text, sometimes this doesn't cut it and I would like to be able to open the HTML attachment in my web browser [Luakit](https://luakit.github.io/).

Is there a way to transparently do this? A good workflow for me would look like:

1. open mail (Lynx converts it)
2. see that it is too complicated for Lynx
3. press <kbd>v</kbd>
4. navigate to HTML attachment
5. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the mail in Luakit.

Comment: This doesn't work for you ? `text/html; luakit %s` besides, auto_view doens't matter in this case, since html are actually attachments

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do this with mutt's [mime support](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mutt).

> In addition, you can use this with Autoview to denote two commands for viewing an attachment, one to be viewed automatically, the other to be viewed
> interactively from the attachment menu.

Essentially, you include two options in your `mailcap` file<sup>1</sup>.

```
text/html; luakit '%s' &; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; needsterminal;
text/html; lynx -dump %s; nametemplate=%s.html; copiousoutput;
```

The first entry tests that `X` is running, and if it is, it hands the file to luakit. The default, however, is determined by the `copiousoutput` tag, so it will be rendered in Mutt by lynx.

You will need these options in your `.muttrc`:

```
auto_view text/html                                   # view HTML automatically
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html  # save HTML for last
```

If you want to look at it in your browser, it is just a matter of hitting <kbd>v</kbd> to view the attached HTML and then <kbd>m</kbd> to send it to mailcap.

For convenience, I bind <kbd>Enter</kbd> to that function in `muttrc`:

```
bind attach <return>    view-mailcap
```

<sup>1. Note, I don't use lynx or luakit, so these options are indicative only.</sup>
<sup>Shamelessly reproduced from this blog post: https://jasonwryan.com/blog/2012/05/12/mutt/</sup>

Comment: If you want to avoid the `needsterminal` for `luakit` have a look a Gary Johnsons [`mutt-netscape` script.](http://www.spocom.com/users/gjohnson/mutt/#html)

Comment: Does it really have to read `text/html; text/html; luakit ...` with the text/html repeated?

Comment: Is there a way to do this while disabling the loading of external resources (for privacy reasons)?

Comment: @a3nm That all depends on the settings in the browser you hand off to...

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes... I'm looking for a way to invoke Firefox in a way that would disallow any external lookups.

Comment: @a3nm I don't know, but I suspect there are privacy extensions for that.

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, but of course this only applies to mail loaded in mutt, not to all the browsing I do, so it isn't that easy to find something satisfactory...

Comment: Invoking flirefox from the commandline with a specific special profile is easy - that way you could have a private profile specifically for mail reading.

Comment: latest Wayback Machine snapshot of the [`mutt-netscape` script](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425091539/http://www.spocom.com/users/gjohnson/mutt#html)

Comment: +1 This answer is the base I use. For mine, I just want to hook up with `firefox`, thus my first line in `~./.mailcap` is `text/html; [ $DISPLAY != "" ] && firefox %s &; needsterminal;`, second line is the same, and no `auto_view` in `muttrc` as I prefer text-based.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mutt#Viewing_HTML), I have this in muttrc to open HTML in my $BROWSER (Firefox, really) when pressing <kbd>V</kbd> in the attachment view:

```
# pipe-entry pipes the current entry to iconv. iconv converts text from one character encoding to another
# See this for a description of Mutt functions: https://muttmua.gitlab.io/mutt/manual-dev.html#functions
set my_mail=/tmp/mutt/mail.html
macro attach V "<shell-escape>mkdir -p $(dirname $my_mail)<enter><pipe-entry>iconv -c --to-code=UTF8 > $my_mail<enter><shell-escape>$BROWSER $my_mail<enter>" "Open attachment with $BROWSER"
```